# How could a just God design vessels whose only purpose is damnation, as predestination seems to teach?

Tags: nature-of-god, reformed-theology, predestination, unconditional-election

> [Romans 9:20–23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+9%3A20-23&version=NKJV) (NKJV)
>   But indeed, O man, who are you to reply against God? Will the thing formed say to him who formed it, “Why have you made me like this?” <sup>21</sup> Does not the potter have power over the clay, from the same lump to make one vessel for honor and another for dishonor? <sup>22</sup> What if God, wanting to show His wrath and to make His power known, endured with much longsuffering the vessels of wrath prepared for destruction, <sup>23</sup> and that He might make known the riches of His glory on the vessels of mercy, which He had prepared beforehand for glory,

I was introduced to Calvinism not too long ago and the scriptural argument is pretty strong. I really don't know how a God who claims to be just could eternally punish those who were destined, forced, and could only do evil.  There isn't really a point to knowing the difference between good and evil if we have zero power to control ourselves or to seek God.  Are there people trying to be reborn who are just wasting their time because they're not elected?  How can Calvinists have children knowing there's a good chance that some of them might not be elected and are destined to live a useless life of 70-80 years on earth and then burn forever simply because God wanted them to for whatever reason?  This has really brought me to question the Bible as a whole to be honest.

Comment: Also related: [According to Calvinism, why does God give mercy to some and not to others?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33767/21576)

Comment: According to Calvinists, the passage you quoted addresses your issue: "who are you to reply against God?"

Comment: Other Christian traditions share your concerns about Calvin's double predestination. Catholics teach that this would be a serious affront to God's goodness, his lovingkindness, his truth, and his justice, and that while all men have a common destiny, no one is fated to go to Hell and God has a universal salvific will, Ezekiel 33:11.

Comment: @Steve As a child of God wanting information.

Comment: Read Ezekiel 33 - God desires that the wicked would turn and live.